# synchronous xmlhttprequest on the main thread is deprecated lead to unexpected behaviour

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1, myfaces 2.0. Previously was using PrimeFaces 3.5, it is working fine. I have p:dataTable with p:commandLink. I have a server side method to clear filters. When I click on either p:commandLink in p:dataTable, it will go to another page but console is showing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearFilters' of undefined". It only happened when p:commandLink is clicked. Any idea why?

**xhtml**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="620"><p:dataTable styleClass="dataTable" id="db1001_datatable_dashboards" 
                    paginator="true" rows="50"
                    paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50,75,100,200"
                    resizableColumns="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                    value="#{pc_Db1001.w_dashboard.listOfDashboards}"
                    var="varlistOfDashboards" filteredValue="#{pc_Db1001.w_dashboard.listOfFilteredDashboards}" 
                    widgetVar="listOfDashboards">

                    <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{pc_Db1001.filterListener}"></p:ajax>

                    <p:column id="db1001_column_selector" width="20">
                        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="selectBooleanCheckbox"
                            id="db1001_checkbox_checkbox"
                            value="#{varlistOfDashboards.selected}"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        <f:attribute value="top" name="valign" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="db1001_column_chart_type" style="text-align: left;font-weight: 400"
                        width="100" sortBy="#{varlistOfDashboards.chart_type_dn}"
                        resizable="true" headerText="#{msg.db1001_gridheader_chart_type}" 
                        filterBy="#{varlistOfDashboards.chart_type_dn}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains" 
                        filterStyle="width: 90px;align: left;"
                        filterStyleClass="filterInputText" 
                        filterValue="#{pc_Db1001.w_dashboard.fv_chart_type_dn}">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridText"
                            id="db1001_gridoutput_chart_type_dn"
                            value="#{varlistOfDashboards.chart_type_dn}"></h:outputText>
                        <f:attribute value="true" name="nowrap" />
                        <f:attribute value="top" name="valign" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="db1001_column_category" style="text-align: left;font-weight: 400"
                        width="90" sortBy="#{varlistOfDashboards.category_dn}"
                        resizable="true" headerText="#{msg.db1001_gridheader_category}" 
                        filterBy="#{varlistOfDashboards.category_dn}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains" 
                        filterStyle="width: 80px;align: left;"
                        filterStyleClass="filterInputText" 
                        filterValue="#{pc_Db1001.w_dashboard.fv_category_dn}">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="outputGridText"
                            id="db1001_gridoutput_category"
                            value="#{varlistOfDashboards.category_dn}"></h:outputText>
                        <f:attribute value="true" name="nowrap" />
                        <f:attribute value="top" name="valign" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="db1001_column_shortname" style="text-align: left;font-weight: 400"
                        width="350" sortBy="#{varlistOfDashboards.shortname}"
                        resizable="true"
                        headerText="#{msg.db1001_gridheader_shortname}" 
                        filterBy="#{varlistOfDashboards.shortname}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains" 
                        filterStyle="width: 340px;align: left;"
                        filterStyleClass="filterInputText" 
                        filterValue="#{pc_Db1001.w_dashboard.fv_shortname}">
                        <p:commandLink ajax="false" styleClass="commandLink"
                            id="db1001_commandlink_shortname"
                            action="#{pc_Db1001.doDb1001_commandlink_shortnameAction}">
                            <h:outputText id="db1001_gridoutput_shortname"
                                styleClass="outputGridText_80px"
                                value="#{varlistOfDashboards.shortname}"></h:outputText>
                            <f:param name="db1001_click_rptsysid"
                                value="#{varlistOfDashboards.rptsysid}"></f:param>
                        </p:commandLink>
                        <f:attribute value="true" name="nowrap" />
                        <f:attribute value="top" name="valign" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column id="db1001_column_maintain" width="60">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:commandLink ajax="false" styleClass="commandLink" id="link1"
                            action="#{pc_Db1001.doDb1001_commandlink_configureAction}">
                            <h:outputText id="db1001_commandlink_maintain"
                                styleClass="outputGridText_px"
                                value="#{msg.db1001_commandlink_configure}"></h:outputText>
                            <f:param name="db1001_click_rptsysid"
                                value="#{varlistOfDashboards.rptsysid}"></f:param>
                        </p:commandLink>
                        <f:attribute value="true" name="nowrap" />
                        <f:attribute value="left" name="align" />
                        <f:attribute value="top" name="valign" />
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Request bean**

```
private void setFiltersNull() {
    String _LOC = "[Db1001: setFiltersNull]";

    W_dashboard _w = getW_dashboard();

    _w.setListOfFilteredDashboards(null);
    _w.setFv_chart_type_dn(null);
    _w.setFv_category_dn(null);
    _w.setFv_shortname(null);
}

public void clearFilters() {
    String _LOC = "[Db1001: clearFilters]";

    W_dashboard _w = getW_dashboard();

    try {
        setFiltersNull();

        //get datatable
        DataTable table = (DataTable) findComponentInRoot("db1001_datatable_dashboards");

        if (table != null) {
            //clear sort
            ValueExpression ve = table.getValueExpression("sortBy");
            if (ve != null) {
                table.setValueExpression("sortBy", null);
            }

            //clear filtering
            String _widgetVar = table.getWidgetVar();
            String jsFunctionStr = "PF('" + _widgetVar + "').clearFilters();";
            RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.execute(jsFunctionStr);

            //reset datatable
            table.reset();
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void filterListener(FilterEvent filterEvent) {
    String _LOC = "[Db1001: filterListener]";
//      System.out.println(_LOC + "1.0");

    W_dashboard _w = getW_dashboard();

    try {
        //Get datatable
        DataTable table = (DataTable)filterEvent.getSource();

        //Clear checkbox in main list
        List _main_list = _w.getListOfDashboards();
        List _filtered_list = _w.getListOfFilteredDashboards();

        if (!isEmptyNull(_main_list)) {
            for (Iterator iter = _main_list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                W_dashboard _wm = (W_dashboard) iter.next();

                _wm.setSelected(false);
            }
        }   

        //Clear checkbox in filtered list
        if (!isEmptyNull(_filtered_list)) {
            for (Iterator iter = _filtered_list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                W_dashboard _wm = (W_dashboard) iter.next();

                _wm.setSelected(false);
            }
        }   

        //Retain filters by setting to managed bean
        //From listing page, click new, cancel out to listing page, the filter is not "remembered"
        Map filters = table.getFilters();
        System.out.println("1.0 " + " filters:" + filters);

        if(filters != null) {

            //dashboardid
            String _filterText = (String)filters.get("chart_type_dn");
            if(!isEmptyNull(_filterText)) {
                _w.setFv_chart_type_dn(_filterText);
            }else {
                _w.setFv_chart_type_dn(null);
            }

            //category
            _filterText = (String)filters.get("category_dn");
            if(!isEmptyNull(_filterText)) {
                _w.setFv_category_dn(_filterText);
            }else {
                _w.setFv_category_dn(null);
            }

            //description
            _filterText = (String)filters.get("shortname");
            if(!isEmptyNull(_filterText)) {
                _w.setFv_shortname(_filterText);
            }else {
                _w.setFv_shortname(null);
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public String doDb1001_commandlink_shortnameAction() {
    String _LOC = "[Db1001: doDb1001_commandlink_shortnameAction]";
//      System.out.println(_LOC + "1.0");

    Map _rp = getRequestParam();
    String _rptsysid = (String) _rp.get("db1001_click_rptsysid");
    W_dashboard _w = getW_dashboard();

    if (_rptsysid != null) {
        Integer _rightid = _w.getDashboardRightsid(_rptsysid);
        if (_rightid == null) {
            showCommonMessage_ByKey("db1001_message_delete_noaccessright_setup");
            return null;
        } else {
            if (cannotAccess(_rightid.intValue())) {
                showCommonMessage_ByKey_With3Parameter("db1001_message_delete_noaccessright"
                        , _rightid, null, null);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    //clear sorting and filtering
    clearFilters();

    return "db1001_commandlink_shortname_success";
}
```

**Error on console**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearFilters' of undefined(…)
    (anonymous function) @ db1001.xhtml:534
    i @ jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=5.1:25
    fireWith @ jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=5.1:25
    ready @ jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=5.1:25
    bZ @ jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=5.1:25
```

Comment: Try to print out jsFunctionStr, and run it in the console

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar How to run that in the console? Does it matter to call clearFilters() in non-ajax commandLink?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I tried to run it in the console. Same error.

Comment: It seems you're navigating to another page, yes? In which the datatable widgetvar is not available, so it will fail. And I'm not sure if its possible to use the context.execute(...) on a full request, as you mention

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Do I need to make a code change to cater for this? Because I still do not have an idea why.

Comment: Well whats the downside to just removing the clearfilters() call? Will they be remembered when you navigate back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130188/discussion-between-bittersour-and-jaqen-hghar).

Comment: Sorry but I can't right now

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I tried to do it without making the call to clearFilters(). The filter text still stays there.

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I suspect the error I am facing is due to "synchronous xmlhttprequest on the main thread is deprecated"

Comment: But is it correct that you navigate to another page, click back, and then the filters are still there?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar When filtered something, go to another page and back, filter text shouldn't be there. I managed to workaround it. I posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
String _widgetVar = table.getWidgetVar();
String jsFunctionStr = "PF('" + _widgetVar + "').clearFilters();";
```

Change to:

```
String _tableid = table.getId();
String jsFunctionStr = "$('#" + _tableid + "').find('thead > tr > th.ui-filter-column > .ui-column-filter').val('');" + "$(this.jqId+'\\\\:globalFilter').val('');" + "this.filter";
```